# Use value of token (strtok) in function in c

Tags: c, function, token, strtok

I got a bit confused using token, say if:

```
int main(void) {
    char input[100];
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    char * token = strtok(input, " ");
    char * height = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char * width = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (height > 9 && width > 9)
        set(height, width);
}

void set(char * height, char * width) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width + 1; j++) {
            mine[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

I just found that i can't use "height+1", can anyone tell me any way to use the value of height? Besides, should i put char *height and char *width in void set?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you comparing `char *`s with integer constants? That's a constraint violation, your compiler should have complained about that.

Comment: In `set` function, `height` and `width` are pointers... you should dereference them (`i<*height+1;`) or convert them into intergers (`strtol(...)`) before using them.

Answer (score 0):

[`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/?kw=strtok) cuts the c-string into pieces and returns pointers to the delimited substrings.

So with your code, if you enter "480 640", the pointer `height` will point to "480" and the pointer `width` to "640".  So they point to (ascii) strings not to integers.

If you need integers, you first have to convert them, for example with [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi):

```
int main(void){
  ...
  char *token=strtok(input, " ");
  char *s_height=strtok(NULL, " "); // these are strings
  char *s_width=strtok(NULL, " ");
  int height=atoi(s_height), width=atoi(s_width); // convert to integers
  ... 
}

void set(int height, int width){
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading from your stream with `fgets()` and tokenizing it, you should convert your strings into the appropriate integer values.

```
char *heightStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
char *widthStr = strtok(NULL, " ");
int heightVal = atoi(heightStr);
int widthVal = atoi(widthStr);
```

Your `set()` function should also use integers as it's parameter types, not `char*` ie. `void set(int height, int width)`

Comment: I thought of atoi, but i was worried about segmentation fault, because i came across that problem when i wrote a small program on ubuntu. It says segmentation fault(core dumped). So is it safe to use atoi?

Comment: It's always wise to do data validation whenever you are writing a program that takes input from a user.  `atoi` takes a c-string (ie. a null terminated array of characters) as its parameter.  If you check the input and verify that what is being passed to `atoi()` is valid you should be fine.

Comment: You can also use `strtol()` to convert a string to an integer value.